# mariadb IF statements error message?

Tags: mariadb, mariasql

I test sql querys.

```
    IF 3 = 3 THEN 
       SELECT 'TRUE'
    ELSE
       SELECT 'FALSE'
    END IF;
```

I excuted that query on SQLyog.

I got the error message below.

```
 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to 
 your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'ELSE SELECT 
 'FALSE' END IF' at line 3
```

That query is very simple. I don't know why happen error message.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`IF` itself is not a query, it cannot be executed as a standalone statement.

There are two different `IF`s that you can use.

**One** is the [conditional construct in compound statements](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/if/). It can be used in stored routines:

```
DELIMITER $
CREATE PROCEDURE pr()
BEGIN
    IF 3 = 3 THEN 
       SELECT 'TRUE';
    ELSE
       SELECT 'FALSE';
    END IF;
END $
DELIMITER ;
CALL pr;
```

Or, if you are running a reasonably new version of MariaDB (10.1+), you can also use it in an [anonymous block](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/begin-end/):

```
DELIMITER $
BEGIN NOT ATOMIC
    IF 3 = 3 THEN 
       SELECT 'TRUE';
    ELSE
       SELECT 'FALSE';
    END IF;
END $
DELIMITER ;
```

**Another** is the `IF` function, which can be used *inside* a query:

```
SELECT IF(3 = 3 THEN 'TRUE','FALSE');
```

Answer (score 0):

You need semicolons at the end of each inner statement like so:

```
IF 3 = 3 THEN 
   SELECT 'TRUE';
ELSE
   SELECT 'FALSE';
END IF;
```

Comment: SQL Error (1064): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 2